# VS Code shortcut for searching the highlighted text

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a shortcut that would act like **Find in Files** shortcut, but would also perform a search of the highlighted text?

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I guess you are looking for this icon "Find in Selection (Alt+L)"

Just press **Crtl + F** and **Alt + L** to highlight the icon and you are good to go.

[image: Find in Selection]

Comment: Tips: This "Find in Selection" feature can be combined with **Alt + Enter** to select all matching occurrences of searched text in highlighted text  (a.k.a. selected text) with multi-cursor selection.

Answer (score 2):

The 'find in files' shortcut by itself searches for highlighted text '**ctrl+shift+f**'. You can navigate through the results with '**f4**' to get to next one.

If you want to search for all references you can use ' **shift+ f12**'.
If you want to see the list of all shortcuts you can always use '**ctrl+k ctrl+s**' to browse shortcuts and edit them.

Comment: 1. It does not search. It adds the highlighted text to the search input and opens the side bar with this input. 2. It would be great if instead of typing how your shortcuts are configured, you wrote the names of the shortcuts.

Comment: guess you should add '+enter' to first shortcut :) appreciate the downvote

Answer (score 1):

I just uncovered the [Search Under Cursor](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DavidSanders.search-under-cursor) extension which does exactly what I believe is wanted i.e. your cursor is on a word and you want to quickly search all files for that word, without having to select/click the whole word.

I find it interesting that this function isn't baked into VS Code, I run it so unbelievably often. Just saving a reach for mouse and double-click, or an "Expand Selection" keystroke is a huge win for me.

HTH